# How can I use 2 Electron windows (Nightmare + Electron) at the same time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, nightmare

I'm creating web automation software using NightmareJS. I would like to create a GUI for my software but I can't figure out how to have an Electron window and a headless NightmareJS process going at the same time. The goal is to be able to control the NightmareJS thread via the GUI Electron thread. Here's what using Nightmare looks like for me:

```
const Promise = require("bluebird");
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
require('nightmare-upload')(Nightmare);
const vo = require('vo');
const realMouse = require('nightmare-real-mouse');
const request = require("request");
const qs = require('querystring')
const EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const rp = require('request-promise');


var run = function* () {
    const nightmare = Nightmare({
        show: true,
        switches: {
            'ignore-certificate-errors': true
        },
        waitTimeout: 90000,
        gotoTimeout: 90000
    });


    yield nightmare.goto("https://www.google.com");
    yield nightmare.wait(5000);


    yield nightmare.end(() => "some value");
    yield nightmare.then(function () {
        console.log("ended");
    });
}

vo(run)(function (err, titles) {
    console.dir(titles);
});
```